# ¿Cómo cambiar el eje x de gráfico de numero a meses?

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo una base de datos con una columna de los meses que esta como numérica, quiero hacer un gráfico pero que en el eje x se muestre los meses.

la data es la siguiente.

```
MES <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
OPCION_A <- c(2627,2630,2829,2508,2716,2740,2977,2919,2739,2934,2487,2803)
OPCION_B <- c(276,286,333,221,542,159,200,171,389,386,517,378)
df <- data.frame(MES, OPCION_A, OPCION_B)
```

El código del gráfico es el siguiente.

```
library(ggplot)
library(reshape2)

melt_df <- melt(df,id.vars = "MES")

ggplot(data=melt_df,aes(x=as.factor(MES),y=value))+
  geom_col()+facet_wrap(.~ variable,scales = "free")
```

he intentado pasar el eje x de números a meses, con este comando `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"))` , pero me sale error.

Answer (score 0):

El tema es substituir los números de mes por una etiqueta con el nombre de los mismos, puedes crear un vector con este dato o puedes usar el vector que ya tenemos en R:

```
month.abb
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

Y lo puedes usar así:

```
ggplot(data=melt_df,aes(x=factor(month.abb[MES], levels=month.abb, ordered = TRUE),y=value))+
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~ variable,scales = "free") +
  labs(
    x = "Month"
  )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, una consulta adicional, existe la forma de ordenar los meses en forma cronológica.  (Jan, Feb, Mar....)

Comment: Sí, lo más simple es convertir la variable mes en un factor ordenado, en ese caso automáticamente ggplot los ordenará cronologicamente. Revisa https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html

Comment: @OscarMartinez, ahí edite mi respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Patricio.